# How do I disable plugins from command line on visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, resharper, performance

Resharper is killing me  for some reason on startup, I just need to get in, is there a command line switch for load without addins?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are probably looking for the `/SafeMode` [command line switch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee0c8y7(VS.80).aspx):

```
devenv.exe /SafeMode
```

This will start Visual Studio with all add-ins disabled.