# Visual Studio Runtime error

Tags: visual-studio

```
Error   58  The "SubsetFontsWpf" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'Fonts\segoeui.ttf'.
File name: 'Fonts\segoeui.ttf'
  at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
  at System.IO.File.InternalCopy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, 
  Boolean overwrite)
  at Microsoft.Expression.SubsetFontTask.SubsetFontsWpf.WriteFontFiles()
  at Microsoft.Expression.SubsetFontTask.SubsetFonts.Execute()
  at Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.TaskEngine.ExecuteInstantiatedTask(EngineProxy 
 engineProxy, ItemBucket bucket, TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask, ITask task,
 Boolean& taskResult)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Does starting in SafeMode help? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885636/how-do-i-disable-plugins-from-command-line-on-visual-studio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the error message, basically, it looks like you miss a [font](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segoe) file.

Two solutions:

- You can try to find the missing file on internet, and put it in the correct folder (I'm guessing Visual Studio has a folder for this, and if not, add it to the Windows fonts). *I wouldn't really recommend that, though, as it would probably mean some illegal download (fonts are not simple free objects)*
- It's not normal that you miss a file which looks to be "original" from Visual Studio, so if this file misses, maybe others do too, and in this case you should reinstall Visual Studio

Answer (score 1):

A font used by Visual Studio is missing.  Drop segoeui.ttf back into your /Fonts folder and all will be well again.