# Visual&Install (unSigned s.r.o.) causes all Visual Studio to crash

Tags: visual-studio, installation, inno-setup, visual-and-installer

Using **InnoSetup** and **InnoSetup Script Studio** for a while with success. But there is one missing feature: Debugging includes **.iss** files. So I installed **Visual&Install (unSigned s.r.o.)** to evaluate it and to see if it allows debugging includes .iss files (having one main .iss files and several "modules").

The Result after installing **Visual&Install** is that it causes *all my Visual Studio installations to crash* after launching:

[image: Visual&Install causes Visual Studio to crash all the time]

Any suggestions? I'll try to contact **Visual&Install** support but I need a quick solution since I need Visual Studio for development ...

--hfrmobile

Comment: I don't know that product, but if disabling all the add-ins is an option for you, you may try [this way](http://stackoverflow.com/a/885653/960757). If not, you can try to uninstall that add-in from Programs and Features (I believe it has an entry there), and wait for an update that you'll install back into your VS (though I can't say how persistent will be user configuration, if there is some).

Comment: ... some further information (Windows Event Viewer, Stack traces):
http://1drv.ms/1TTMAP7

Btw, using Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: TLama, thank you for the hint. I simply uninstalled it. It is strange for me since the "plugin installer" UI was in German (bad, automated translation) and I wonder who likes using development software in German .... I am used to use Visual Studio etc. in English .... Maybe it is the cause of the problem ... NullReferenceException ... already contacted their support ... Let's see what the answer will look like ;-)

Comment: Maybe you'll get the answer here. The author is a registered Stack Overflow user. About the setup language, I guess the detection is by the system language, not by the language used in VS. About the included files debugging, I could come up just with one pretty [ugly workaround](http://pastebin.com/09daBaBh) :)

Comment: Windows system message is English. I guess there is a more "sophisticated" --> Europe/Austria --> German .... In my point of view it does not really make lot of sense providing such an tool in German anyway ;-) Thanks for the workaround, I'll give it a try!

Comment: Don't take that *workaround* seriously :) It just preprocess the script (inlines all the files), saves it to a file and opens that file in a new IDE instance. All that when building (CTRL + F9), which is totally user unfriendly.

Answer (score 0):

Simply disable the extension which may cause crash and Start Visual Studio.

As the Visual & Installer extension is tested probably there is no problem directly in this extension but this extension may collide with some other.

Comment: Application: devenv.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.NullReferenceException
Stack:
   at VisualInstaller.ApplicationUpdater.OnGetLatestVersionFinished(System.Object, VisualInstaller.DownloadInfo, VisualInstaller.DownloadInfo, VisualInstaller.DownloadInfo)
   at VisualInstaller.ApplicationUpdater.Invoke(VisualInstaller.DelegateGetLatestVersionFinished, System.Object[])
   at VisualInstaller.VersionDownloader.GetLatestVersionThreadFunction(System.Object)......

Comment: as you can see the Visual&Installer plug-in is causing the crash. Already uninstalled and everything is fine. Looking forward to see fix soon.